# Iterate through entries of column and calculate with them

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to iterate through the entries of one specific column and calculate with the entries. My table looks like that:

```
FreeKB (Column to iterate) | FileSystem | Date      | System  |
---------------------------|------------|-----------|---------|
          5000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-28| TestSys |
          7000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-27| TestSys |
          3000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-26| TestSys |
         10000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-25| TestSys |
          9000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-24| TestSys |
          8000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-23| TestSys |
         10000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-22| TestSys |
         11000             |   TestFS   | 2017-03-21| TestSys |
```

The question is: How do I iterate through all the entries of "FreeKB" and calculate with them? To be more specific: I want to calculate the median of all entries, where the amount of FreeKB is **shrinking**. I'm familiar with scripting and a little bit c++ but I'm a newbie to SQL.

Sorry if the answer seems obvious...

Greetings

Edit:

For the result, I want to iterate somehow through the entries of the last 7 days for each single FileSystem and System in the table, look where the amount of FreeKB shrinks, and calculate the median of the shrinking-numbers. Example: From 2017-03-27 to 2017-03-28 the amount of FreeKB shrinks by 2000 KB, 25th to 26th by 7000, 22th to 23th by 2000. I want to get the median of the numbers and calculate when the FileSystem might become full for an E-Mail

Comment: Do you really need a solution for both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]? They're different products. If you could explain what the *results* you're expecting would look like (as another table?) then it might make it clearer what you're looking for. In *general*, in SQL, we try to write *set-based* solutions, rather than [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: For the result, I want to iterate somehow through the entries of the last 7 days for each single FileSystem and System in the table, look where the amount of FreeKB shrinks, and calculate the median of the shrinking-numbers. Example: From 2017-03-27 to 2017-03-28 the amount of FreeKB shrinks by 2000 KB, 25th to 26th by 7000, 22th to 23th by 2000. I want to get the median of the numbers and calculate when the FileSystem might become full for an E-Mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CrossApply in SQL Server
Here are some link to get you started with

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/18/sql-server-cross-apply.aspx
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

Here is sample Code

```
CREATE TABLE #test (FreeKb int,FileSystem varchar(50),[Date] Datetime)
INSERT INTO #test
SELECT 1001,'TestFS','2016/12/14' UNION
SELECT 1111,'TestFS','2017/01/01' UNION
SELECT 1223,'TestFS','2017/01/15' UNION
SELECT 1233,'TestFS','2017/01/02' UNION
SELECT 1321,'TestFS','2017/01/31' UNION
SELECT 1400,'TestFS','2016/12/12' UNION
SELECT 1456,'TestFS','2017/03/13' 

SELECT a.*,b.newColumn FROM #test a
cross apply(
SELECT a.FreeKB/(SELECT count(FreeKB) from #test)as NewColumn
)b
```

Comment: Thanks, but this post was misstaged for SQL-Server. I wanted to tag it for mssql, somehow it got changed to SQL-Server..

Comment: Well... just figured out, SQL-Server on stackoverflow means mssql... I'm sorry, thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem. Hope the solution is helpful to you.